# Does a language describe things beyond itself?

Tags: objective-c

I now have sufficent exposure to the Objective-C that if i'm stuck with anything, I know how to think of the problem in terms of a likely tool I need and go look for it. Simple really. There's A Method For That. So nothings a real problem anymore.

Now I'm looking deeper at the language in broader terms. We write stuff. The compiler hews out all the code to execute it. From a simple flashlight app thats a if/then decision to turn on, to a highly complex accelerometer driven 3D shoot 'em up with blood 'n guts and body parts following all sorts of physics, the compiler prepares the code ready to be executed like a giant railway layout. No matter how random it appears on the screen, everything possible can be generically described and prepared for.

So here's the question:
Are there cases where something completely unexpected to the software designer can still be handled without an execution halt?  Maybe I'd better re-frame the question a few different ways: Can a ( objective-C ) program meta-compile within itself in response to an unplanned-for user request?  or to re-put my opening remark, are there tools or methods for unlikely descriptions of unlikely problems?

Comment: Are you trying to describe metaprogramming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming)?

Comment: had a quick look and will follow the links further. It seems to be an established school of thought. 15 months ago, as a total Noob, the language loomed larger than Everest. In the last week, i didn't notice anything go 'click' but I now find myself wondering. "..Is that all there is to it? Is it really that simple? to describe your problem in terms of the tools available to solve it?" Build. Run. Submit.

Comment: at the risk of it being not kocher to write two comments in a row,, what led me to pose the question was an app i wrote that has methods  to cater for error-handling and others for hardly-used situations. If the User never uses them, the code is still written and loaded into the device. It made me wonder if I could tell the compiler not to worry about assembling that code until its needed. One could think of externally referencing code 'modules' but that's cheating? So can my app do it from within?

Comment: You can load code at runtime, but you will still need _some_ code to catch the error condition and load the handling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [@kfb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246534/kf) has the right comment about metaprogramming.  Check out the Runtime docs in conjunction with metaprogramming tutorials.

Parts of your last question might be in the realm of [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html).

If your looking for ways to reduce the size of your code base for the lesser used features, one idea might be to make the features internet based (assuming connectivity is not a problem).